# How to read files from HDFS in Reducer using Rhipe (R)

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on creating multiple mappers and reducers. The two mappers and reducers does its stuff, and saves the output in HDFS output folder. Now, I need to read these two reduced files from HDFS from the third reducer, but couldn't figure out how to. I'm doing map-reduce using Rhipe. Here's the code:

```
reduce.test <- (expression(
  pre = { 
     total <- 0 
     #read file from previous reducers -- this didn't work
     pos.mod <- readLines("/path/to/file/in/hdfs")  

    #error received: Error in file(con, "r"); cannot open connection

  }, 
  reduce = { total <- sum(total, unlist(reduce.values)) }, 
  post = { rhcollect(reduce.keys, total) }

))
```

Comment: use hadoop streaming :)

Comment: @B.Mr.W. Could you please elaborate? I'm not sure how I can use Hadoop Streaming from reducer using R. Thanks

Comment: See my answer, there is a little bit over head in the reducer part writing hadoop streaming, but once you are done with that once, it is done forever.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is just another option for using R to crunch big data set, instead of using `Rhipe`, I have some experience using hadoop streaming and that works really well to me.

In a short sentence, you can use any language to write map reduce jobs using [Hadoop Streaming.](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html)

Here is some code that I have written before just to give you a brief idea of how it looks like in R.

You can customize your own `myfunction` and it should be almost there.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(dplyr)
f <- file("stdin")
open(f, open="r")
mydelimiter <- '\t'
mydelimiter_col <- rawToChar(as.raw(1))
myfunction <- function(inputarray){
    ...
    return(result)
}

# FIRST LINE
firstline <- readLines(f, n=1)
fields <- unlist(strsplit(firstline, split=mydelimiter))
mykey_current <- fields[1]
myvalue_array <- array(fields[2])

while( length(line<-readLines(f, n=1)) > 0){
    fields <- unlist(strsplit(line, split=mydelimiter))
    mykey_new <- fields[1]
    myvalue_new <- fields[2]

    if (identical(mykey_new, mykey_current)) {
        # Same Key: append new value to existing value array
        myvalue_array <- c(myvalue_array, myvalue_new)
    } else {
        # Different Key
        # (1): process existing values
        result <- myfunction(myvalue_array)
        cat(mykey_current); cat(mydelimiter)
        cat(result); cat('\n')
        # (2): reset key, value
        mykey_current <- mykey_new
        myvalue_array <- array(myvalue_new)
    }
}

# LAST LINE
result <- myfunction(myvalue_array)
cat(mykey_current); cat(mydelimiter)
cat(result); cat('\n')
```

To run the hadoop streaming job. I write a little bash that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
hdfs dfs -rmr <hdfspath_output>

hadoop jar \
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.0-1.cdh5.1.0.p0.53/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.3.0-mr1-cdh5.1.0.jar \
-files mapper.py,reducer.R \
-input <hdfspath_input> \
-output <hdfspath_output> \
-mapper mapper.py \
-reducer reducer.R
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I must use Rhipe for this project. Everything else works really well, except for reading for file in reducer.